# Converting timestamp to date and keeping only date in a list inside pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df which looks like:

`df`

```
date

[2021-08-31 00:00:00]
[2021-07-02 00:00:00, 2021-07-02 00:00:00]
[2021-08-31 00:00:00, 2021-09-15 00:00:00]
```

When I export it to `.csv` I get a column looking like :

```
date

[Timestamp('2021-08-31 00:00:00')]
[Timestamp('2021-07-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-07-02 00:00:00')]
[Timestamp('2021-08-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-09-15 00:00:00')]
```

I want the `.csv` file to have the same look as in `df` without the `Timestamp` and preferably without the hours, minutes, and seconds.

What I tried:

Checked if I can convert it like so:

```
for nr, item in enumerate(df['date']):
    print(pd.to_datetime(item[nr],format='%Y%m%d'))
    print(type(item[nr]))
    break
```

But it still returns seconds which I don't understand why if I added the `format` parameter.

```
2021-08-31 00:00:00
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

I tried:

```
def to_date(df):
    res = []
    for nr, item in enumerate(df['date']):
        res.append(item[nr].date())
    return res

df['test'] = to_date(df)
```

But I get:

> IndexError: list index out of range

And I am not sure how I should convert it so that in my `.csv` file I would get dates that would look like this `2021-08-31`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `map()` and list comprehension:

```
df['date']=df['date'].map(lambda x:[str(y) for y in x])
#you can also use apply() or agg() but they are slower then map()
```

Finally use `to_csv()` method:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

**Update:**

If you want only date part then:

```
df['date']=df['date'].map(lambda x:[str(y.date()) for y in x])
#as suggested by @MrFuppes
```

Comment: This removed the `Timestamp` string but kept the hours minutes and seconds. I added `[:10]` to get the dates but I still think there should be a way to deal with this without converting it to string but with `datetypes` somehow.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis you might use `.map(lambda x: [y.date() for y in x])` - but the csv file will basically be only string, so you could just use the proposed str method.